# Group by filtering non-group by field

Tags: c#, ravendb

How can I do a Group by filtering in a non-group by field? I'm using c# connected to a RavenDB database.

I'm new to RavenDB, and I'm trying to run a basic group-by query with no success, neither on RQL nor c#. I'm using Raven.Client lib 4.1.3

```
var results = await session.Query<Order>()
    .Where(s => s.Date <= new DateTime(2019,1,1))
    .GroupByArrayValues(x => x.OrderItems.Select(y => y.ProductName))
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Product = x.Key,
        Total = x.Sum(s => s.Itens.Sum(i => i.ItemValue))
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Total)
    .ToListAsync();
```

When I run this code I got an AggregateException from the Raven.Client lib. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the exception details to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue... Some strings were bad formatted (with blank spaces in the end) so the aggregate/groupby could not aggregate and sum them properly.

Interesting fact is that SQL Server (the source of my testing data) ignore this and sum all the looked alike results together. So if there is a wrong database here, is SQL Server.